# TeX で数式や記号を表示させたい。

Tags: latex

TeXにて以下のように入力しました。
TeXが入っているディレクトリには、amssymb.styとamsmath.styが入っています。

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{jreport}
\usepackage{suthesis}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{listings,jlisting}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\lstset{
%プログラム言語(複数の言語に対応，C,C++も可)
language = Python,
%背景色と透過度
%backgroundcolor={\color[gray]{.90}},
%枠外に行った時の自動改行
breaklines = true,
%自動改行後のインデント量(デフォルトでは20[pt])    
breakindent = 10pt,
%標準の書体
basicstyle = \ttfamily\scriptsize,
%コメントの書体
%commentstyle = {\itshape \color[cmyk]{1,0.4,1,0}},
%関数名等の色の設定
classoffset = 0,
%キーワード(int, ifなど)の書体
%keywordstyle = {\bfseries \color[cmyk]{0,1,0,0}},
%表示する文字の書体
%stringstyle = {\ttfamily \color[rgb]{0,0,1}},
%枠 "t"は上に線を記載, "T"は上に二重線を記載
%他オプション：leftline，topline，bottomline，lines，single，shadowbox
frame = TBrl,
%frameまでの間隔(行番号とプログラムの間)
framesep = 5pt,
%行番号の位置
%numbers = left,
%行番号の間隔
stepnumber = 1,
%行番号の書体
numberstyle = \tiny,
%タブの大きさ
tabsize = 4,
%キャプションの場所("tb"ならば上下両方に記載)
captionpos = t
}

\graphicspath{{figs/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg}

\blacksquare
```

コンパイルをすると以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.428 \blacksquare
```

■をTeX内に挿入したいです。（その他数式も）

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

追伸1
LaTeXは以下のサイトの通りにインストールしました。
    https://did2memo.net/2016/04/24/easy-latex-install-windows-10-2016-04/

追伸2
エラーの原因が分かりました。

428行目に

```
\blacksquare
```

と挿入されていました。

正しくは、

```
$\blacksquare$
```

と挿入すべきでした。

Comment: LaTeXはどのようにインストールされたものなのか追記して頂けませんか？　また、入力に使った .tex ファイルの中身は質問文にあるものと全く同一でしょうか？　このままだと色々と足りないので、私の環境だと別のエラーが出るのですが……。[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)にして頂けると回答者側で問題が再現できるので回答しやすいです。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。今度はソースコードから `\blacksquare` が消えたようです。エラーが再現できるような小さめのソースコードを頂けるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ソースが提示されていないので詳しいことはわかりかねますが、恐らくソースの428行目に`\blacksquare`という命令が書いてあると思います。しかし、それは数式環境で用いるもので<del>`$\backsquare$`</del> `$\blacksquare$`のように用いるということがエラーからわかります。

Comment: $\blacksquare$と入力すると、■が表示できました！！ありがとうございます！！